# Is there a better word for "Enabledness"?

Tags: word-choice

I just ran across the phrase "button enabledness" in a technical design, but that doesn't look right. Is it a valid word? Is there a better way to express "the state of whether or not something is enabled" (even if it doesn't derive from enabled)?

Comment: I think that "enablement" is a better non-word for the job than "enabledness".

Comment: _enablement_ sounds like the process of enabling. _enabledness_ is the state of whether or not something is enabled.

Comment: @Barmar your interpretation is correct--edited my question to clarify

Comment: Hello c32hedge. What ELU or any other StackExchange site is looking for is questions backed by a reasonable amount of evidence of personal research. Which dictionaries have you looked up the candidate word in? Is it given? How often does it occur on Google?

Comment: Of course it is a word, by definition. So that is not your question. What is your real question? Are you trying to get peole to express revulsion? Are you asking for writing advice? Do you want recommendations for how to disparage the writer? Voting to close as Unclear What You're Asking until you tell us what your real question is, although nearly every other close reason also applies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I did check several dictionaries (Merriam-Webster, Oxford, Dictionary.com), none of which listed it. While the word itself did appear in a number of Google results I would still like a better alternative (amusingly the presence of "web-enabledness" in this list of [cringeworthy words](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/cringeworthy-words-and-phrases-encountered-as-a-corporate-writer-editor) suggests others have had similar reactions.

Comment: @tchrist I was asking whether it is correct usage and if there is a better alternative (since I'm updating a legacy document). I edited the title to clarify.

Comment: In general, it is beter to use several smaller words than one great big long one built up out of cascading affixes.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, 'vonk' is a pseudoword, and pseudowords do not form part of the lexicon: A pseudoword is a unit of speech or text that appears to be an actual word in a certain language, while in fact it has no meaning in the lexicon. Next, someone has to decide who decides what constitutes the lexicon. Even OED has turned down the offer.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31878/noun-for-enable-enability-enabliness

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think *enabledness* is a real word. Words like *antidisestablismentarianism* show that you can combine affixes in many valid ways; it's a fairly general mechanism, like combining clauses into sentences. The rule is that *-ness* can be appended to an adjective to form a word that refers to the state of an object that may or may not have that condition, and *enabled* is a valid adjective describing such a condition.

I think it seems cumbersome because the adjective is a gerund form of a verb, and *-ness* is more often used with simple adjectives, e.g. *sadness*. Off the top of my head I can't think of a simple adjective that means *enabled*, so that we could append the suffix to it. When new adjectives need to be coined, they often come from verbs like this, and you end up with unfamiliar combinations as you derive other forms from them.

If you want something that sounds more playful, you could use *enableditude*.

UI elements that are enabled are also sometimes referred to as *active*, so *activeness* could be another alternative.

Comment: Disantiestablismentarianness, antiantidisestablismentarianism, quasiantidisestablismentarianism ...; ininflammable, ignice, polyactive, ceruleanness, amethystness,  ...  show that 'you can combine affixes in almost arbitrary ways' is far from the truth.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I said _almost_.

Comment: I'd want 'often quite productive ways'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Take a look at the edit.

Comment: We mustn't encourage D-I-Y words-or-are-they. (I may delete this one later.)

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Barmar's answer. It's just that the concept of a button being enabled or disabled is so far from most folks' concerns that enabledness is going to sound funny. By the same token, a logical equivalent, disabledness, sounds even worse.

Avoiding an unfamiliar construction at the cost of some brevity, you might try **button enabled/disabled status**.

Comment: It seems to me that the context for this would be a technical document, not the general public, so "most folks's concerns" may not be very important.

Comment: "Enabledness", whether understandable or not, is ugly. Might as well use "Disabledness" for the same setup. Ugly words for the sake of brevity have all the charm of GOTO statements in 80's BASIC. They're *jarring* and disrupt the flow of understanding.

Answer (score 2):

While it wouldn't work in every situation, "clickability" would work here since the primary use of enabling/disabling a button is to determine whether it does anything when you click it.